# "MyClass mc = MyClass()" or "MyClass mc"?

Tags: c++, initialization

What is the difference between

```
MyClass mc = MyClass();
```

and

```
MyClass mc;
```

in C++?

Comment: first is copy intialization and other is default initialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first invokes copy constructor, with temporary object as parameter - `MyClass()` creates temporary.

The second invokes default constructor.

In reality, they are, in most cases, optimized out to the same code, but that's the semantical difference.

---

As *Negal* mentioned, the case is a bit different with POD types; when "MyClass" is POD, the second snippet will not value-initialize `mc`, whereas first will.

Comment: + 1 for telling temporary thing.

Comment: Even though both cases are optimized into the same thing, there is at least 1 case when the results are different. If `MyClass` is a POD (plain old data) type, `MyClass mc` will not cause `mc` to be value-initialized when `mc` is local variable. The second approach will create a value initialized temporary and initialize `mc` with it.

Comment: Good point, and still, whether they are optimized to the same thing or not depends on what's in the default constructor and in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is copy initialization and the 2nd one is default initialization.

For example, the following code will not compile:

```
class MyC
{
public:
MyC(){}
private:
MyC(const MyC&) {}
};

int main()
{
  MyC myc = MyC();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does show the difference. If the copy constructor is private, one is legal and the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

Custom copy constructor and default constructor.

Comment: `operator=` is not invoked here.

Answer (score 0):

First create `temp-object` via `c-tor without arguments` and then calls `copy-ctor` for object (no take in account any optimisations). Second calls `c-tor without arguments`, without copy. With compilers optimization both cases are equal.

Differences are in fundamental-types, so

```
// initialized to something
int c;
// initialized to int() that is 0 by standard.
int c = int();
```

Answer (score -3):

no difference. default ctor call. syntax sugar ) 
no copy ctor!!!!

```
class PPP{
public:
    PPP(PPP&){
        std::cout<<"PPP1"<<std::endl;
    }
    PPP(const PPP&){
        std::cout<<"PPP2"<<std::endl;
    }
    PPP(){
        std::cout<<"PPP3"<<std::endl;
    }
};
PPP ppp = PPP();
```

and you find only PPP in  the console.

Comment: Printing the same, how you understand which constructor is called? Also, this may be optimized by the compiler, turn off any optimization options (-O0) and try again :)

Comment: printing PPP only onece )) not in def and copy ctors ). without optimization ) /Od

Comment: and of cource you can test this: PPP ppp = PPP();PPP ppp1 = ppp; copy only in the 2 stetment )